# In Sencha touch2 How to enable browser's scrollbar

Tags: sencha-touch-2

For some reason, I like to use browser's native scrollbar instead of sencha's.

I already set overflow to auto to body, but still don't see scrollbar until I set a fixed height to "ext-viewport" manually in chrome toolbar say 2000px.

it looks like viewport always auto fit to screen size.
is there any settings to disable this and enable browser's scrolling?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Updates on May 19**
Here's some progress,

1. In `Ext.viewport.Android` -> `doFixSize` will auto fit the viewport to screen size, comment this out and then set/detect fixed
2. in `Ext.viewport.Default`, it swallows `touchstart/touchmove` event so the scrollbar doesn't work, by setting `preventPanning/preventZooming` to `false` I can get the scrollbar working.
   it scrolls much faster than sencha's scrollbar :)

carousel doesn't work well now, investigating...

---

**Updates on June 20**

Carousel won't work with native scrollbar in android 4 due to below bug
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827

with native scrollbar, only touchstart and the first touchmove event is invoked, the subsequent touchmove and touchend are lost so it's not possible to implement carousel without e.preventDefault().

one workround is to listen to touch events, when event target is carousel, then call e.preventDefault to disable native scrollbar....

Answer (score 0):

try this code

`Ext.viewport.setScrollable(false);
                            Ext.viewport.element.dom.childNodes[0].style.overflow = 'scroll';`